# Chrome extension manifest v3 service worker does not update

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

The screenshot summarizes what happens to a chrome extension manifest v3 service worker. The service worker does not update when clicking **Update** or when refreshing the page and **Update on reload** is checked.

Instead, the current service worker never unloads and the updated service worker does not properly start.

Is there anyway to prevent this or to always have it skip waiting?

[image: chrome extension devtools]

Comment: Click `skipWaiting`.

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue and my popup shows the message "Waiting For Service Worker."